# How to use an input value variable in an ajax call triggered by a modal button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm generating dynamically a table with products for sale, an input to select the amount of products, and a button to process the purchase in each row. Then I'm making an AJAX call to process  all this data and show a modal dialog displaying the data.

Something like:

Product  Unit-price  Number

Product A         12         [input amount] [purchase button]

I intend to get a modal  with "You have purchased * items of * for $ *."

Works fine, but it all gets spoiled when I try to catch the input value to display the  number of items.

This is the table body:

```
          <?php

          foreach ($result as $doc) {

            $price = $doc['2'];
            $name = $doc['1'];
            $rd_price = round($price, 2);
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                <td class="product_price"><?php echo $rd_price; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="product_qty" value="0"></td>
                <td class="amount_sub_total">0</td>
                <td><button  data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#myModal" id="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $rd_price; ?>" onclick="showDetails(this)">
                   <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </button></td>
            </tr>
      <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
```

And the script:

```
<script>

function showDetails(button) {
  var customerNumber = button.id;
  var customerPrice = button.value;
  var selectedAmount = $(.product_qty).val();


      $.ajax({
      url: "customer.php",
      method: "GET",
      data: {"customerNumber": customerNumber, "customerPrice": customerPrice, "selectedAmount": selectedAmount},
      success: function(response){
        $("#value").text(response);

      }

  });

}

 </script>
```

I'd be quite grateful if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed quotes "".
change this

`$(.product_qty).val();`

to this

`$(".product_qty").val();`

And would be less error-prone if you would use `id` instead of `class` css selector

something like using button_id in combination with `product_qty`

`$("#product_qty_"+button.id).val();`

and update html to something like

`<input type="text" name="qty" class="product_qty" value="0" id="'product_qty_'+<?php echo $name; ?>">`

Comment: Sorry, in a more thorough test I just realised it works but only with the first item on the table. The rest of the rows just show the default value.

Comment: that is because you are using `class` csss selector which selects collection.. try above code

Comment: So you mean adding a id="product_qty_" to the input and then going like var selectedAmount = $("#product_qty_"+button.id).val();?

Comment: yes.. something like `<input type="text" name="qty" class="product_qty" value="0" id="'product_qty_'+<?php echo $name; ?>">`

Answer (score -1):

You missing something in this.

```
    <tbody>
<?php
    foreach ($result as $doc) {
        $price = $doc['2'];
        $name = $doc['1'];
        $rd_price = round($price, 2); ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            <td class="product_price"><?php echo $rd_price; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="product_qty" value="0"></td>
            <td class="amount_sub_total">0</td>
            <td><button  data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#myModal" id="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $rd_price; ?>" onclick="showDetails(this)">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            </button></td>
        </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</tbody>

<script>

function showDetails(button) {
    var customerNumber = button.id;
    var customerPrice = button.value;
    var selectedAmount = $(button).parents('tr').find(".product_qty").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "customer.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: {"customerNumber": customerNumber, "customerPrice": customerPrice, "selectedAmount": selectedAmount},
        success: function(response){
            $("#value").text(response);
        }
    });
}
 </script>
```